# How do I open all files in the current directory and all subdirectories using vim?

Tags: vim

So far I've been using `vim */**` which seems to open all files in subdirectories but *not* those in the current directory, and `vim *` which opens all files in the `current` directory. But how do I open all files in the current directory *and* all subdirectories?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
vim ./**/*(.)
```

Other shells:

```
find . -name '.?*' -prune -o -type f -exec vim {} +
```

To open only the (non-hidden) *regular* files (not directories, symlinks, pipes, devices, doors, sockets...) in any level of subdirectories.

---

```
vim ./**/*(D-.)
```

Other shells, GNU `find`:

```
find . -xtype f -exec vim {} +
```

To also open hidden files (and traversing hidden directories) and symlinks to regular files.

---

And:

```
vim ./***/*(D-.)
```

other shells:

```
find -L . -type f -exec vim {} +
```

to also traverse symlinks when looking into subdirectories.

---

If you only want one level of subdirectories:

```
vim ./* ./*/*
```

Note that it's a good habit to prefix your globs with `./` in case some of the file names start with `-` or `+`.

(of course the `find` ones also work in `zsh`. Note that they may run several instances of `vim` if the list of files is big, and at least with GNU `find`, will fail to skip hidden files/dirs whose name contains sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in your locale).

Answer (score 1):

In bash with `shopt -s extglob`:

```
for file in **/**; do [[ -f "$file" ]] && vim "$file"; done
```

Note that, as per [Stéphane's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149355/how-do-i-open-all-files-in-the-current-directory-and-all-subdirectories-using-vi/149357#comment242606_149357), prior to Bash 4.3 this would follow any symlinks in the directories covered.

Comment: That runs one `vim` per file though. Note that bash before 4.3 used to traverse symlinks with `**`. It's been fixed in 4.3.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Is one vim per file bad *per se* (assuming we are talking about several files, rather than several hundred)? Thanks for the note about the symlinks: I'll edit that in.