# shell globbing to open all files with vim not working as expected

Tags: shell, vim, wildcards

I'm trying to open and edit a series of files with vim. My expected behaviour, is that vim opens one file, I edit it, type `:wq`, vim closes and saves that file, and then immediately opens the next file for me to start editing.

I did some googling, and [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081332/open-all-files-in-a-folder) [results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149355/how-do-i-open-all-files-in-the-current-directory-and-all-subdirectories-using-vi) profered the solution of `vim *` or `vim pattern*`, with variations on standard unix shell file globbing syntax.

However, when I try this on my system, I get unexpected behaviour. After I edit and `:wq`,  vim seems to open that same, first file again (with the saved changes), and then another `:wq` dumps me back on the command line. No other files were opened for editing

**Edit** I tried two methods to escape the asterisk, in case something wasn't reading the glob properly

```
$ vim webform.webform.\*

$ vim "webform.webform.*"
```

However both of these syntaxes gave me a vim screen where it was editing a new file with the literal name `webform.webform.*`

Here's what I originally attempted, with the unexpected behavior:

```
$ vim webform.webform.*
```

Vim opens the first file:

```
...   ...
100   draft_pending_multiple_message: ''
101   confirmation_type: page
102   confirmation_title: ''
103   confirmation_message: ''
"webform.webform.my_webform.yml" 184L, 8621C
```

I edit the file, save, and close it:

```
:wq
```

Vim notes that the changes were written, indicates how many files are left to edit, wants me to hit enter for some reason:

```
"webform.webform.my_webform.yml" 184L, 8621C written
E173: 130 more files to edit
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Then it opens again the same first file that it just opened.

```
100   draft_pending_multiple_message: ''
101   confirmation_type: page
102   confirmation_title: ''
103   confirmation_message: ''
                            1,1           Top
```

I save and close:

```
:wq
```

Now I'm back at the bash prompt, no additional files opened in vim.

```
$
```

I want to open a file, edit it, save it, close it, and edit the next file. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 21 2019 04:10:35)
...

$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
...
```

Comment: You want to use ":w" to write the file rather than ":wq" (write and quit), and then ":n" or ":next" to get to the next file.

Comment: [Close and unload a buffer without exiting Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3066/close-and-unload-a-buffer-without-exiting-vim) and [How do I close a buffer (out of many) in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269648/how-do-i-close-a-single-buffer-out-of-many-in-vim)

Comment: @icarus that appears to be just what I needed-- want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Thanks, but let someone else post a full answer handling removing the buffers, the differences between vi and vim in this area, adds in :rewind and the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the wildcards. It is that each file is opened in a buffer, and you cannot use `:wq` to exit a buffer. You could use `:w|bd` to save the current buffer and unload it. I find it clumsy, though. Much better is to add the `-p` flag when invoking Vim:

```
vim -p webform.webform.*
```

This causes each file to be opened in a new tab, and then you can use the `:wq` (or `:x`) to save the file and close the tab.

Comment: Suppose halfway through I decide I don't actually want to edit all 160 files right now. How do I exit out of all these "vims" at once?

Comment: `:xa` or `:wqa` saves and close all tabs. `:qa` quits all tabs (if no modification was made to any of them).

Answer (score 0):

Based on icarus' comment, using `:wn`, `write` then `next`, instead of `:wq` gets me the desired behavior, and I don't have to enter two separate commands into vim.

Comment: Notice there is a slight difference between this and the expected behavior: With `:wn` the saved files keep open, you are just cycling through then with `:wn` (you could check that going back one file with `:bp`). I don't think that is a problem, but just to make it clear.