# Difference between GNU find -not and GNU find -prune -o -print

Tags: find, gnu, syntax, dot-files, file-search

This answer on opening all files in vim except [condition]:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149356/98426

gives an answer similar to this:

`find . \( -name '.?*' -prune \) -o -type f -print`

(I adapted the answer because my question here is not about vim)

Where the negated condition is in the escaped parentheses. However, on my test files, the following

`find . -type f -not -name '^.*'`

produces the same results, but is easier to read and write. The -not method, like the -prune method, prunes any directories starting with a . (dot). **I am wondering what are the edge cases where the -not and the -prune -o -print method would have different results.**

Findutils' infopage says the following:

-not *expr*: True if expr is false

-prune: If the file is a directory, do not descend into it. (and further explains that -o -print is required to actually exclude the top matching directory)

They seem to be hard to compare this way, because -not is a test and -prune is an action, but to me, they are interchangeable (as long as -o -print comes after -prune)

Comment: Doesn't the first also exclude files in hidden directories? Simple test case: Run in the top level of any git repository.

Comment: @Quasímodo
My goal is to understand the difference between -prune -o -print and -not

The linked answer did not fail so solve my problem. My question was inspired by the answer.

I believe my question is self contained. It has nothing to do with the linked question per se.

I also believe that this all is obvious from my question. I am open to suggestions about how to make the question more clear.

Comment: Your `find` with `-not` *doesn’t* exclude directories starting with `.`; it will output any file name not starting with `^.`, regardless of any `.`s in its path components. Try it in a git workspace as muru suggested. (`-name` doesn’t match regexes.)

Comment: @StephenKitt You are right, I confuse globs and regexes. Do you think I should edit the question and replace ^. with .* to reflect my original intention or should I leave it like this?

Comment: @YordanGrigorov even if you used `.*`, it would still match filename not starting with `.` inside directories whose name do start with `.`.

Comment: @YordanGrigorov please leave the question as-is, the existing answers address that confusion so removing it would be unfair to their authors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that `-not` is a GNU extension and is the equivalent of the standard `!` operator. It has virtually no advantage over `!`.

The `-prune` predicate always evaluates to *true* and affects the way `find` walks the directory tree. If the file for which `-prune` is run is of type *directory* (possibly determined after symlink resolution with `-L`/`-H`/`-follow`), then `find` will not descend into it.

So `-name 'pattern' -prune` (short for `-name 'pattern' -a -prune`) is the same as `-name 'pattern'` except that the directories whose name matches `pattern` will be *pruned*, that is `find` won't descend into them.

`-name '.?*'` matches on files whose name starts with `.` followed by one *character* (the definition of which depends on the current locale) followed by 0 or more *characters*. So in effect, that matches `.` followed by one or more characters (so as not to prune `.` the starting directory).

So that matches hidden files with the caveat that it matches only those whose name is also entirely made of *characters*, that is are valid text in the current locale (at least with the GNU implementation).

So here,

```
find . \( -name '.?*' -a -prune \) -o -type f -a -print
```

Which is the same as

```
find . -name '.?*' -prune -o -type f -print
```

since AND (`-a`, implied) has precedence over OR (`-o`).

finds files that are *regular* (no symlink, directory, fifo, device...) and are not hidden and are not in hidden directories (assuming all file paths are  valid text in the locale).

```
find . -type f -not -name '^.*'
```

Or its standard equivalent:

```
find . -type f ! -name '^.*'
```

Would find regular files whose name doesn't start with `^.`.

```
find . -type f ! -name '.*'
```

Would find regular files whose name doesn't start with `.`, but would still report files in hidden directories.

```
find . -type f ! -path '*/.*'
```

Would omit hidden files and files in hidden directories, but `find` would still descend into hidden directories (any level deep) only to skip all the files in them, so is less efficient than the approach using `-prune`.

Comment: Although Kusalananda's answer was easier for a noobie to understand, I have to admit that your answer covers a lot more of the find utility and ultimately gave me a deeper understanding of what is going on.

Comment: _It has virtually no advantage over `!`._ The advantage is the syntax collision with shell history expansion in `bash`.

Comment: @Riking, `!` alone is left alone by csh history expansion (copied both by bash and zsh). If it weren't you'd have problems not only with `find` but also with `test`/`[`, (`[ ! -f file ]`) and the `!` shell keyword. `find`/`test` existed before `csh` and `csh` existed before GNU `find`.

Answer (score 5):

The `-prune` predicate in `find` removes a branch of the search tree.  Therefore, using `-prune`  as in the first command in your question would only give you the same results as your second command if there are no files in directories with hidden names.

Example:

```
$ tree -a
.
|-- .hiddendir
|   `-- file
`-- dir
    `-- file

2 directories, 2 files
```

```
$ find . \( -name '.?*' -prune \) -o -type f -print
./dir/file
```

```
$ find . -type f ! -name '.*'
./dir/file
./.hiddendir/file
```

(I corrected the `-name` test here as you seem to use a nonsensical regular expression, and I used `!` in place of the non-standard `-not`).

As you can see, since the name `.hiddendir` matches the globbing pattern `.?*`, it is removed from the search tree with the first command, and the `file` file beneath it is not found.

In the second command, the `.hiddendir` directory is not pruned from the search tree, so the `file` file in there is found.

Comment: Note that even if `^.*` were a regular expression, it wouldn't make much sense as it would match anything (any number (`*`) of characters (`.`) at the start of the subject (`^`)). To match on hidden files, that would be `^\.`, or `\..*` for regexps implicitly anchored at the start and end (like GNU `find`'s `-regex`, though that `-regex` matches on the full path, not the just the name).

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is the easier one to follow since you focused on the highlighted part of my question.